# How to send cell data from template sheet to main sheet in Microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a production management sheet for a cafe. which has a main sheet called production, Production has a new customer button which creates a new sheets and pro-grammatically copy invoice Template and pastes in newly created sheet . all i want automatically send and SUM the total of each item form all sheets to the master Production sheet. i can do it in general but when inserting new template(in newly created sheet) using button click its a bit tricky.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Then
   If MsgBox("Name and Address are Important", vbQuestion + vbOKOnly) <> vbYes Then


   Exit Sub
   End If
  End If

TotalSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
CheckSheet = TextBox1.Value

For i = 1 To TotalSheets
 If LCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name) = LCase(CheckSheet) Then
   If MsgBox("This Customer Name Already Exists, Choose a different Name", vbQuestion + vbOKOnly) <> vbYes Then


  Exit Sub

 End If
End If


Next
Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = TextBox1.Value
Worksheets("Invoice").Cells.Copy Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you narrow the question down to what is actually causing you trouble. For example, do you need help creating a loop that includes all sheets in a workbook?

Comment: ok, so all i want is when new sheet is created , and i enter data for example i enter 5 in quantity as you can see images above. i want the entered data in new sheet to be added in the production sheet.  for example if 3 customers order one bread loaf i want all these to be added and shown in production sheet.

Comment: How is the data getting to the front page? By a macro or by a formula?

Comment: its by formula. but all i want is combine the 'order' column data of all sheets. so i want data entered in 'order' in newly created sheet to be SUM with 'order' column front page in front page.

Comment: Okay, so is your actual problem then: How to create/update a sum formula to include new sheets added by a macro?

Comment: yes. you got that right. sorry i am bad at explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I get this right, you have a master worksheet named `Production`, a worksheet that serves as a template for the invoices, named `Invoice` and two other worksheets named `Recipes` and `Nav`.

For now I will assume you don't have any more worksheets.

Each time you create a new customer, a new worksheet is created based on the `Invoice` template. What you need is some code that will calculate the sum of all the individual orders, which then should be populated in the `Production` sheet.

My suggestion would look like that:

```
Sub updateTotalOrders()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sumOfOrders As Long
sumOfOrders = 0
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Production" And sht.Name <> "Invoice" And sht.Name <> "Nav" Then 'add here any other sheets that should be excluded from the sum
        sumOfOrders = sumOfOrders + sht.Range("C4")
    End If
Next sht
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production").Range("") = sumOfOrders 'Use whichever range you want
End Sub
```

The code I provided only works for "Sandwich Loaf" obviously, but can easily be extended to include all other items. I am just giving you an idea on how to continue.

To summarize, this code basically loops through all the worksheets and checks if they correspond to a customer. If they do, then it updates a sum. When the looping stops, the final result is passed to `Production`.

Comment: thank you so much .I understood the code so which event should i call this code in.sorry I am coming from java background .

Comment: You could assign it to a button in your `Production` worksheet for example. In that way the user could create multiple new customer sheets, complete the appropriate data and when they are done they can go to the `Production` worksheet and press the button to update the orders overview.

Answer (score 1):

If all sheets have the same layout, the simplest method is to use formulas with sheet ranges. If you need to start off with less than 2 invoices, then create two dummy invoice sheets with all Orders as blank or zero so they don't impact the totals. If the two dummy sheets are called A and B, then create formulas like this on your main page:

```
=SUM(A:B!A1)
```

This will sum cell A1 on all sheets between sheets A and B.

Make sure sheets A and B are the last two sheets in your workbook then change your code to insert all new invoices in between them:

```
Sheets.Add before:=Sheets("B")
```

Then hide sheets A and B so that users can't see them. You can make it so that users can't unhide them by using a special setting available in the visual basic editor. In the visual basic editor, select the sheet, make sure Properties are visible from the View menu, then set the Visible property to Very Hidden:

[image]

---

The other approach is to modify the formula strings for every formula to include the new sheet.